# find date from input and compare

Tags: javascript, date, compare

i have two input with date... i will second date > first date. i have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var inputData1 = null;
var inputData2 = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var fields = $('.ms-formbody');
    $.each(fields, function(index,Element){

       var elemHTML = Element.children[0].innerHTML;

       if(elemHTML.match(/FieldInternalName="Data1"[^<]*/i) ){
          inputData1 = Element.children[0].children[1];

       }

       if(elemHTML.match(/FieldInternalName="Data2"[^<]*/i) )
       {
          inputData2 = Element.children[1].children[0];
       }


    });

    alert('Pamiętaj, by data1 nie była większa od data2');
    }

);</script>
```

I needs compare date and display message when user use less date in date2(input) then date1 - input...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `inputDate1` and `inputDate2` into JavaScript Date objects or a [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) date wrapper.

```
var date1 = moment(inputDate1, "MM-DD-YYYY"); //or whatever format is used
var date2 = moment(inputDate2, "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

Compare the two dates using regular comparator operators.

```
if(date1 > date2){
    alert('error, second date is before the first date');
}
```